# using tkinter module with python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write simple things in a Tkinter module  using python 3.6 in Anaconda. This is my code

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
thelabel = label(root, text="this is our tk window")
thelabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

but I get the error:

```
TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed
ERROR: execution aborted
```

and I keep getting a blank Tkinter window whenever I run my code and I don't understand what is the problem, thanks:)

Comment: try with an L for `Label`:  `   thelabel = Label(root, text="this is our tk window")`

Comment: Is this _really_ your code? tkinter doesn't export anything with the name `label`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error...

Here is the correct way:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
thelabel = Label(root, text="this is our tk window")
thelabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

You should try reading a bit on tkinter.

Here are some [references](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/)  specifically on [label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm).

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: I don't think this is correct answer. Using `label` raises error that `label` is not defined.

Comment: As you can see in the references (you can look at the website under 'label') the uppercase name 'Label' works... if you have doubts you can run the code provided in the answer. @BlackThunder let me know if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
thelabel = Label(root, text="this is our tk window")
thelabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Labels start with a capital L not small l it will fix your error